# Problema com collectionView

Tags: swift, xcode, iphone, apple

Olá, boa tarde.

Estou enfrentando um problema com o collectionView swift, ele simplesmente não aparece, eu não entendo muito bem essa questão, mas ele não entra na rotina do collectionView Cell, não sei se é realmente assim o funcionamento também, por isso gostaria de contar com a ajuda de vocês, abaixo vou colocar o código que estou utilizando do collectionView:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        //   let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CarCollectionViewCell
        //   cell.container.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor

        //let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CarCollectionViewCell




        checkvaluecollectioncell = indexPath.row

        self.selectvalue = 1

        self.markers.removeAll()
        self.driverIds.removeAll()




       if(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "PreferredLanguage") as! String == "en"){

            GlobalVarible.firstcarname = CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].carTypeName!
            GlobalVarible.cartypename = CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].carTypeName!
        }else{
            GlobalVarible.firstcarname = CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].carTypeName!
            GlobalVarible.cartypename = CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].carTypeName!
        }

        GlobalVarible.car_type_id = CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].carTypeId!


        GlobalVarible.cartypeid = CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].carTypeId!

        GlobalVarible.Cityid = CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].cityId!

        // aqui caminho imagem - 20/10/2018
        GlobalVarible.cartypeimage = CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].carTypeImage!


        if CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].rideMode == "2"{

            print("ridemode2")

            ApiManager.sharedInstance.protocolmain_Catagory = self
            ApiManager.sharedInstance.SelectRentalCar(CityID: GlobalVarible.Cityid)

        }else{
            self.mapview.clear()
             self.postdata.removeAll()
            self.datagetfromgeofire()
           //21/10/2018
            //self.GetDatafromfirebase()

        }

        MapCollectionview.reloadData()


    }
```

E tenho outra rotina do collectionView Cell que está abaixo:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = MapCollectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Mapcollectioncell", for: indexPath) as! CarCollectionViewCell



        cell.container.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        cell.container.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        cell.container.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        cell.container.layer.shadowRadius = 2

          //  .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)

        let newString = CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].carTypeImage!
        print(newString)


        let url = imageUrl + newString


        let alerta = UIAlertController(
            title: "Falha de Comunicação",
            message: url,
            preferredStyle: .alert)

        present(alerta, animated: true, completion: nil)



        let url1 = NSURL(string: url)

        cell.carimage!.af_setImage(withURL:
            url1! as URL,
            placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "dress"),
            filter: nil,
            imageTransition: .crossDissolve(1.0))


        if(checkvaluecollectioncell == indexPath.row)
        {


           // cell.container.layer.backgroundColor =  (UIColor(red: 179.0/255.0, green: 191.0/255.0, blue: 191.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) as! CGColor)
         //   cell.container.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

            cell.container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:147.0/255.0, green:165.0/255.0, blue:165.0/255.0, alpha:1.0)

            cell.carname.textColor = UIColor.white
            cell.cartime.textColor = UIColor.white
            //21/10/2018
             //cell.checkRadioBtn.image = UIImage(named: "Circled Dot-35 (1)")

        }else{

            cell.container.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            cell.carname.textColor = UIColor(red:147.0/255.0, green:165.0/255.0, blue:165.0/255.0, alpha:1.0)
            cell.cartime.textColor = UIColor(red:243.0/255.0, green:156.0/255.0, blue:18.0/255.0, alpha:1.0)
            // cell.checkRadioBtn.image = UIImage(named: "Circle Thin-35 (1)")

        }


        cell.carname.text = CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].carTypeName!

        cell.cartime.text = CarsTimedata.details![indexPath.row].baseFare!


        return cell

    }


Eu chamo a rotina assim:

                let indexPathForFirstRow = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                self.collectionView(MapCollectionview, didSelectItemAt: indexPathForFirstRow)


Porem ele não entra na rotina do collectionView Cell, como falei não entendo muito bem como funciona então não sei se é assim mesmo o funcionamento, porem ele so entra na outra rotina do collectionView que é essa:

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

e consequentemente não acessa os dados da rotina que está no collectionView Cell

Se alguém puder me ajudar seria bacana.

Answer (score 0):

Na definição da classe, você deve implementar `UICollectionViewDelegate` e `UICollectionViewDataSource` e em algum lugar, por exemplo no viewDidLoad `collectionview.delegate = self`

Veja também se a sua collectionView está com as constraints corretas na tela para que ela esteja visível o suficiente para aparecer algum item. Se a collectionView não estiver com tamanho, largura definidos talvez o método `cellForItemAt` não seja chamado.

Comment: Opa valeu cara, vou ver aqui, obrigado pela dica.
Abraço.